# "which" refers to which one?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:
"Great helm was worn with a hauberk which also covered the neck and the head of warrior."
The word "which" refers to great helm or hauberk?

Comment: That "which" clearly refers to the hauberk.

Comment: A hauberk is a mail shirt. Presumably needed to provide padding under the great helm.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! *Great helm* and warrior also need articles, probably *the*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that due to the structure of the sentence and where the "which" is placed it seems to point to the "Hauberk"

Answer (score 2):

> The hat was worn with a hairnet which also covered her hair.

Which, who, and (often) that are [relative pronouns](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/which_that_who.htm) used to link to another word in the sentence (very often the one directly preceding it) to add information about that word.

*Which* adds the information *also covered her hair* to **hairnet**.